# jQuery input form validate

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

If I have an html form on it validate works

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
    <p><input type="text" name="user" id="user" "/></p>
    <div class="formInputMistake"  id="errorEmail"></div>   
    <p><input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" /></p>
    <div class="formInputMistake"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    <div class="formInputMistake"></div><!--here i want to show error "wrong password or user"-->
</form>
```

php-file usr.php

```
if(isset($_GET['login']) && isset($_POST['user']) && 
        isset($_POST['passwd']) && isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if($_POST['user'] = "admin" && $_POST['passwd'] == "admin") {
        //successful log in
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
        $_SESSION['passwd'] = $_POST['passwd'];
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

And a jQuery code, using a `validate-plugin` made by Jörn Zaefferer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").validate({
        ignore: ".ignore",
        rules: { email: {...}, loginPasswd: {...} },
        messages: { email: {...}, loginPasswd: {...} },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('usr.php?login', $(form).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
                if(data == 'true') {
                    $('#loginForm').hide();
                } else if(data == 'false') {
                    //Last formInputMistake - showing the  "wrong password or user"??
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How to validate errors coming from the server?

Thank you

Comment: why there will be errors coming from the server can you please explain?

Comment: if you validate data using jquery that would be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

why you write this

```
$_GET['login']
```

i think you should write :

```
$_POST['login']
```

Comment: someone shouldn't use $_GET in case of passing secured data.

Comment: yep and also he is using post method in form so $_GET not work

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use `$_REQUEST['login']`, it's better.